# find all possible element combinations containing the last element in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, combinations, element

I have a vector [x1, x2,...xn]. Is there a way to find all possible combinations of elements that contain the last element xn? For example, if I have 4 elements I want the combinations:

x1,x4

x2,x4

x3,x4

x1,x2,x3,x4

x1,x2,x4

x1,x3,x4

x2,x3,x4

In reality though I have number of elements up to a few hundreds.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you just need the number of permutations or the permutations themself? If you have thousands of elements and need all permutations you also need a lot of patience :p

Comment: Seconding @Ghaul, and you'll need a lot of memory too. For just 100 elements, there are over 6e29 possible combinations...

Comment: What do you need those combinations for?

Comment: With 1000 elements there are 2^999-1 = 5.35e300 of those combinations. You probably want to do something with each combination. Even if that takes only a few picoseconds per combination, that's much greater than the age of the universe. You need to rethink your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really just need to do a choose on all of the elements *except* the last one.

```
C = cell(length(x)-1,1);
for n = 1:length(x)-1
    C{n} = nchoosek(x(1:end-1),n);
end
```

Each element of `C` contains all possible vectors with `n` elements. All you have to do is tack on`x(end)` to each one to get what you're looking for. For example, if `combo=C{4}(7,:)` is one solved set without the last element of `x`, then your desired output is `combo=[combo x(end)]`. To do this for all solutions, just add this line of code inside the loop above:

```
C{n} = [C{n} x(end)*ones(size(C{n},1),1)];
```

**WARNING: With thousands of elements you will run out of memory very quickly. Just 100 elements gives you over 6e29 possible combinations!**

Comment: Practical problems aside, because I'm going to filter my data so the number od elements will decrease dramatically, could you explain what you mean by ''tack on x(end)''? Thank you for your answer.